# Tkinter unresponsive when running input(), worse in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle, turtle-graphics

Hello I found a little issue with using the turtle library and python's IDLE. Observe the following code written in Python 3.5.2:

```
import turtle
turtle.Turtle()
input("Try moving/resizing the window in IDLE. Press enter than try again.")
```

Before pressing enter to give your input, the turtle window will be labeled as unresponsive and not allow the user to resize it. That is, if it's ran with IDLE. However, it works perfectly fine when ran through something such as the windows command prompt or PowerShell.

If ran through IDLE, after the user presses enter the window may **then** be freely moved and resized with no issues. This comes with the drawback that we're no longer inside the script but back to python's shell. Of course, we can still interact with the turtle via the shell but this isn't what I want in my actual application. My main program uses input() to ask the user if they wish to move/rotate and by how much. This remains in an endless loop until the user enters a phrase such as 'quit' to end the program. I will note, even with IDLE the turtle still moves and is drawn correctly. The problem is that the window itself becomes unresponsive. The contents is all correct.

I'm very curious to as of why only IDLE is giving me such behavior... Not only that, is there a way I can keep turtle window from being unresponsive and still make use of input() and the like? Or perhaps there is an alternative I did not think of? My research has lead me to believe this has something to do with TkInter. That would explain why it only works outside of IDLE.

Below is an image that shows my predicament.

[Unresponsive turtle window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y780.png)

Comment: FYI, there is no difference between running python.exe from the cmd shell or powershell. In both cases, python.exe inherits a console handle (for general IPC to the attached instance of conhost.exe) and standard handles for the console's input and screen buffers (unless standard I/O is redirected to a pipe or file). The shell waits on its process handle for python.exe, so it doesn't interact with the console until Python exits.

Comment: When typing into the Windows console -- for either REPL input or entering a line in `input()` -- the turtle window should become unresponsive, because the main thread is blocked and the `PyOS_InputHook` isn't running to update the Tk window. If it's actually still updating the turtle window, then the most likely explanation is that you have pyreadline installed. It doesn't use a cooked read that blocks until the user presses enter, but instead reads raw console input events and can continue to call the input hook to update Tk while the user is entering text.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, the primary issue is with tkinter, not specifically with the turtle app that uses tkinter.  I first reproduced in IDLE with a bare tk window.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
input('prompt: ')
```

I then did the above a line at a time in 3.5.2 running interactively in Command Prompt on Win10.  The second line displays a bare window, add a entry in TaskManager, and adds a Python icon to the task bar.  Clicking back and forth between CP and Tk causes the the corresponding window and icon to get the 'active' appearance.  The window border shifts from gray to black, whereas the icon background shifts from black to gray.

While typing the input statement, but before hitting return, the Tk window shows 'not responding' (after a couple of seconds) both on the title bar and in TaskManager.  The mouse over the inside of the window becomes the blue busy circle.  The window becomes 'active' as described above, and can be moved, but cannot be resized and cannot be closed normally (clicking on [X] brings up the "Not responding, close or wait?" box.

When the statement is Entered, the tk window becomes normally responsive again.  As soon as the 'user' enters anything, the tk window becomes unresponsive in the manner described above, until entry is completed with Enter.

If you retry in CP and enter some characters without hitting Enter, do you see the same unresponsiveness?

Differences in IDLE's shell: creating root puts a new entry in TaskManager, but the new window is attached to the IDLE icon.  While the input statement is being written, the Tk window remains normally responsive.  So at this stage, IDLE is better.  When the input() statement is Entered, the Tk window becomes, as you noted, completely unresponsive (cannot move) even before any entry.  This part is worse.

I tried one further experiment: running IDLE with the -n ('no subprocess') option.

```
C:\Users\Terry>python -m idlelib -n
```

In this mode, there is no problem that I could detect (unlike CP).  This was still true when I ran turtle.  You can ignore the deprecation warning for now.

Comment 1:  IDLE is designed for development and learning, not for production execution.  But it can be used for the latter if there is an advantage to doing so.  You would just have to check that using -n does not introduce any other problems, or rather, that turtle and your code do not interfere with IDLE when running in the same process.

Comment 2: GUI programs usually do not use input and print.  They are usually run without a console to interact with.  If input() is used, even in the Windows console, user should not touch the window before responding to a prompt.

Comment 3: GUI programs usually use GUI widgets instead to fetch and display info.  Turtle makes this more difficult, but not impossible, as demonstrated by turtledemo.  You might be simplify and adapt the code in turtledemo/**main**.py.

Comment: tkinter registers [`EventHook`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Modules/_tkinter.c#l3381) as the `PyOS_InputHook` function. This hook gets called by [`my_fgets`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Parser/myreadline.c#l26) when reading via `PyOS_ReadLine` in the console REPL and `input`. The hook breaks out of the update loop as soon as `_kbhit` returns true. Then a line of input is read using `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole`. Tk widgets aren't updated again until this call returns. BTW, you don't need `input` to see this; just type in the REPL.

Comment: Currently in the 3.6 beta `PyOS_Readline` doesn't call the `PyOS_InputHook` function. It's a bug that I've mentioned to Steve Dower, but I keep forgetting to create an issue for it.

Comment: IDLE is totally different. It doesn't use the REPL and `input` reads via a simple `PyFile_GetLine` call. The `readline` gets proxied over the socket from the worker process to the IDLE shell. While it's waiting for the line of input, the main loop in the worker process obviously isn't calling [`handle_tk_events`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Lib/idlelib/run.py#l58).

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for the explanation of what I observed.  I should have pointed out tha the blockage which entering `input('p : ') had nothing to do with the specific text being entered.  I was concerned whether there is a fixable 'bug' in IDLE and have concluded not.  Prompt handling of gui events and blocking input calls are not compatible except in the peculiar situation of `idle -n`, which has other problems.